# Difference in select query result on MyISAM Vs InnoDB MySQL engines(especially for FULL TEXT SEARCHES)

Tags: sql, innodb, myisam, mysql

I would like to know if there is any difference in the result output of the same select query on MyISAM Vs that on InnoDB for the same table.

The thing I am aware of is MyISAM can do FULL TEXT searches. But will the order of the output differ ?

Comment: No, for non full text searches, there will be no difference.  Order is determined by the `order by` clause in the query.  No other order is guaranteed

Comment: How about for a FULL TEXT SEARCH? Let me update my Question. As of MySQL 5.6 versions and later InnoDB allows FULL TEXT Searches too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of the output is determined by the `order by` clause.  You have three possibilities.

First, there is no `order by` clause.  Then the result set is in an indeterminate order.  You cannot say that running the same query on the same data will produce results in the same order on multiple runs.  You definitely cannot make any statement about runs on different databases.

Second, there is an `order by` clause and it is a stable sort -- meaning that each key for the order by uniquely identifies each row (there are no ties).  Then the results are specified by both the SQL standard and MySQL documentation.  The result sets will be in the same order.

Third, there is an `order by` clause and there are ties.  The keys will be in the same order in both result sets.  However, because keys with ties can be in any order, the two result sets are not guaranteed to be in the same order.

Summary:  if you want results in a particular order, use `order by`.